# Finding angles of hyperbolic triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I am trying to learn about how to find the angles of hyperbolic triangles. Now below is a problem:

[image]

It has all the steps but I am not understanding the concept (the ones that are underlined in green and yellow)

If you notice, $\measuredangle BAC=\frac{\pi}{2}-\measuredangle OAP=\measuredangle OPA$ but I do not know why.

On the other hand, I understand the computation parts but it is meaningless if I dont get the concept.

Anyone can help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\measuredangle BAC$ is the angle centered at $A$ (and not, e.g. $B$). The geodesic $AC$ is orthogonal to the geodesic $AP$ (why?), implying the first relation. The second is similar, you only have to reflect the angle $\measuredangle 0BQ$ about the tangent to $BC$ in $B$.

The last equation in your question ("if you notice") is true, cause $OPA$ is a Euclidean rightangled triangle in which the angles sum up to $180°$. (This is part of the technique, to find helper triangles in which Euclidean geometry applies..)

**Edit:** it is, of course, essential for this reasoning, that the upper half plane is a conformal model of Hyperbolic space, i.e. the Euclidean angles are equal to the Hyperbolic ones.

Comment: So why is$ \measuredangle BQO = \frac{\pi}{2}- \measuredangle QBO?$ In other words, why not $\measuredangle QOB = \frac{\pi}{2}- \measuredangle QBO$? Also, is $CP$ orthogonal to $AC$?

Comment: $QOB$ is a Euclidean triangle with a right angle at the origin, so the angle at $O$ it is equal to $\pi/2$. The first equation you are asking about ($\measuredangle BQO = \pi/2 -\measuredangle QBO$) is just a restatement of the fact that in the Eucilidean triangle $QOB$ the angles sum up to $\pi$ which means that the two angles opposite to the right angle sum up to $\pi/2$. And yes, $CP$ is orthogonal to $AC$ since it's the radial vector which is orthogonal to the tangent of the circle (in the Euclidean geometry) and that carries over to hyperbolic space. Please read the 'Edit' in my answer.

Comment: Everything is becoming clearer now. Here is my final question, to calculate $\measuredangle A$, why was $\measuredangle APO$ used instead of $\measuredangle OAP$? In other words why is $\measuredangle A$=$\measuredangle APO$ but not $\measuredangle A$=$\measuredangle OAP$

Comment: @Mark I do not understand this question. What is $\measuredangle A$? $A$ is a point which belongs to several (hyperbolic) triangles in the picture. The first line (underlined in yellow) is just an elementary calculation. The first equality just says that the two angles depicted at $A$ sum up to $\pi/2$. The second one just uses the relation that angles in Euclidean triangles sum up to $\pi$ -- $\measuredangle OAP$ and $\measuredangle OPA$ are two angles in a Euclidean triangle, the third angle is just a right angle, hence the equality.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

$ AB,BC, CA$ are sides and parts of *semicircles* centered on x-axis with centers respectively at Infinity, Q and P... Angle between two lines also equals angle between their perpendiculars.

The semi-circles are geodesics in ( one of two) Poincare's hyperbolic geometry models.